# How can I figure out a nested radical?

Tags: nested-radicals

I have to find the value of:
( The picture )
[image]

And I have this solution:
[image]

Now, I understood how they took 
$x = \sqrt{1+2x}$
$\implies x^2-2x-1= 0$

But how did they take $(x-1)^2 = 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ x^2-2x-1 = \underbrace{x^2-2x+\color{red}{1}}-\color{red}{1}-1  = (x-1)^2-1-1 = (x-1)^2-2$$

so $$ x^2-2x-1 = 0\implies (x-1)^2=2$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I got this :)

Comment: This "trick" is sometimes called "completing the square".